# window not defined while import AgoraRTC from 'agora-rtc-sdk-ng' in nextjs

Tags: next.js, agora.io

I get an error window is undefined while importing agora.io.

Comment: Looks like Next is trying to do SSR, you won't be able to use the Agora SDK with server-side rendering

Answer (score 1):

Kindly import it like shown below

```
    const AgoraRTC = (await import('agora-rtc-sdk-ng')).default
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

AGORA uses "window" object which is a client side object and Next JS renders on server side. So You need to use "dynamic" for client side rendering. Via Dynamic you can import the file on client side so it will work.

You should copy your whole Agora code and put it in a file. 
For example in my case I put it in "../components/**agoraclientside.js**" 
So in my **index.js** file I wrote :

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const ClientSideControls = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import("../components/agoraclientside");
  },
  { ssr: false }
);
```

Then in your return function use `<ClientSideControls />`